# What is the longest legal statement block you can make with only C# keywords?

Tags: c#, keyword

I was writing some code in C#, and I found myself writing:

```
return new MyClass(...
```

when I noticed that both the `return` and the `new` were both C# keywords. So I wondered what is the longest legal sequence of keywords in C#. All I could think of is:

```
internal static override void MyFunc(...
```

Where `internal static override void` are all keywords. Can you think of a longer sequence of keywords?

Note: There's really no point to the question. I'm just hoping to pour more some fun on the fire :-)

Comment: Isn't this more like "anti golf"?

Comment: hmm yes, static override - well to be honest, he didn't say the code had to compile... ;-)

Comment: Oh, but I wish it did compile! I'm merely lacking coffee and sleep :-)

Comment: i must say, cool question :-) fun c# programming trivia!

Comment: Well, the 7 is all distinct terms... no braces... I assume you'll let me keep white-space?

Comment: OK - it's a community wiki now :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For 6:

```
new protected internal unsafe virtual decimal Foo() {...}
```

Edit for 7:

```
new protected internal unsafe virtual extern decimal Foo();
```

If we allow brackets and braces...

(**edited** the "lock", "new object()", "as" and "string" were contributed by others; see comments)

```
decimal Bar() {
    lock (new object() as string) {
        if (true) {
            checked {
                unsafe {
                    try {
                        do {
                            return default(decimal);
                            unchecked {break;}
                            continue;
                        } while (false);
                    }
                    catch { throw; }
                    finally { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are counting characters:
new protected internal unsafe virtual extern string Foo();

Comment: you might add: lock(new object()) {} somewhere ;)

Comment: string / decimal... got me. it is early here.

Comment: could change the return type to decimal, and then 'return (decimal) new double(); :p

Comment: If it wasn't for 'as' not working with value types: return (decimal) new float() as double; hehe

Comment: as long as you're allowed to use braces, you could replace new object() as string; with: new bool[] { null as string is int }

Comment: also, you could replace default(decimal) with (object)typeof(default(decimal)) for two cheap extra keywords.

Comment: Selected Answer - because it's the most creative!

Comment: `throw null;` adds another keyword.

Comment: @Brian - it could be `async void` too (instead of decimal)... not sure I can squeeze an await in easily, though

Comment: @Marc: Good one. I guess the bottom line is that it can get pretty hairy if really want to :)

Comment: Add async in method declaration for one more keyword.

Comment: @TanveerBadar: either `extern` or `async` not both.

Comment: `catch when (true)` is another easy way to squeeze out some more keywords.

Answer (score 36):

I guess it's infinite:

```
return null as string as string as string as string as string....
```

Comment: Would this affect the compiler?

Comment: The number of different keywords is limited, so you can't produce an infinite chain without repetitions. But you can produce pretty long chains:
return true is bool as object is int as string is byte as double...

Comment: Well, Marc's example is repeating '{' and '}' pretty many times, and those are not even keywords ;-)

Comment: true I guess, but should we count spaces as repeated non-keyword too then? :p just kidding, hehe. I found your answer the most clever one. but I find Marc's the longest without repeating (even though the brackets are repeated).

Comment: This is turning into Just a Minute. http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/comedy/justaminute.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Here is another case that can be as long as you wish:

```
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do // ...
while(x) while(x) while(x) while(x) while(x) // ...
```

With contextual keywords you can also have

```
await await await await await await await // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

10 with extern partial hacks

```cs
abstract partial class A
{
    private protected virtual extern unsafe ref readonly delegate*<int> Test();
}

partial class B : A
{
    private protected sealed override unsafe partial ref readonly delegate*<int> Test();

    // 1        2       3       4       5      6       7     8     9        10
    private protected sealed override extern unsafe partial ref readonly delegate*<int> Test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
internal protected static volatile string foo = "bar";
```

That's 5.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant with method definition (found by my colleague):

```
protected internal override sealed unsafe async void await() { ... }
```

Makes 8 keywords in a row. Uses the fact that `await` is a contextual keyword, so it can be reused for method name.

Comment: in that context await is not a keyword

Comment: @koryakinp: nevertheless `await` _is_ a contextual keyword per se. The original post didn't require the identifier be a keyword exactly in the context as presented in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Base {
    protected internal abstract ref readonly int MyMethod();
}

public class Sub : Base {
    extern sealed protected internal override unsafe ref readonly int MyMethod();
}
```

Managed to get 9 into a method declaration. Not sure if it's possible to get more in a method declaration

Answer (score -2):

Can I cheat?

```
internal protected static volatile StringBuilder @string = 
  new StringBuilder(int.Parse("12"));
```

Using the fact that I can use a keyword or other reserved term as a variable name if I prepend it with an @ - comes in at 9 if you allow the duplication of StringBuilder.

Comment: StringBuilder isn't a keyword, nor is Parse

Comment: I never knew about the @ thing! But I don't think StringBuilder counts as a keyword. It's just a class, no?

Comment: Fair enough. Also I wasn't count Parse, but was double counting StringBuilder.