# Longest keyword chain?

Tags: java

As I was typing some constants in Java I noticed I had used 4 keywords in a row, which Eclipse highlighted for me: `public static final int`. I then took a break from my regular coding and asked myself (and google with no relevant results) what the longest chain of keywords I can use and still have valid code. After a while, the best I could come up with was this method definition:

```
public synchronized static final strictfp int a() { ...
```

which is 6 keywords in Java. Is it possible to go 7, or even higher? What about other languages?

Comment: Make this a community wiki, else it will probably be closed!

Comment: What is this an exact duplicate of?

Comment: It's been marked as ed of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672977/what-is-the-longest-legal-statement-block-you-can-make-with-only-c-keywords which is similar, but C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside a method body you can chain as many `do`s together as you want:

```
do do do do do do do do 
    break;
while (false); while (false); while (false); while (false); while (false); while (false); while (false); while (false);
```

Comment: Di doo doo doo, di da da da....

Comment: this one feels like cheating, the keywords aren't unique...

Answer (score 1):

Same as your:

```
@deprecated
public synchronized static final strictfp int a() throws java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundException, IllegalCastException  { ...
```