# consecutive keywords in C#

Tags: c#, keyword

I was challenged to come up with a valid example of property/method/class/namespace declaration in C# using 8 consecutive keywords in a row. So far I was able to come up with only 7.

```
abstract class ClassA
{
    protected internal unsafe abstract void GetNumber();
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    async sealed protected internal override unsafe void GetNumber() {}
}
```

What would be an example of using 8 or more consecutive C# keywords ?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9422/write-the-longest-sentence-using-keywords-of-a-programming-language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the longest legal statement block you can make with only C# keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672977/what-is-the-longest-legal-statement-block-you-can-make-with-only-c-sharp-keyword)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33673740/323316 - dupe

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because, entertaining as such puzzles can be, this isn't a practical programming question.

Comment: Also, `extern sealed protected internal override unsafe ref readonly int GetNumber();` racks up 9 genuine keywords in a row (the proposed linked dupe uses `async` in a context where it's not a keyword).

Comment: And for my final offer, I have `extern sealed protected internal override unsafe ref readonly int this[int _] { get; }` at 10 consecutive keywords. (We can't count `int` and `get` because intervening punctuation can't be allowed; if it is, declarations of arbitrary length are possible using tuple types.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert that is golden :)